# installing ganglia on ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, monitoring, ganglia

I am running a 7 node cluster with Apache Hadoop 1.0.4.
I am using it for language translation and looking out for a proper guide to install ganglia on all the cluster node.

Please let me know about any guide which will help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try take a look at [O'Reilly's book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025573.do) about `Ganglia`. There's a good topic about that over there.